# Parameter traveling in SOAP

Tags: web-services

How does parameters in SOAP request is secure than Rest. I know SOAP wraps the message in an envelope and then send it to the web server but does it mean message is secure enough ? And if it is then what is the difference between SOAP envelope and Rest request body.

Answer (score 0):

There are web service protocols for passing encrypted data - but you need to make sure it's supported by the relevant frameworks you use.
Note that it's not something that is part of default soap

REST web services are generally less "standard", and i'm not aware of a standard way to add encryption in rest (beyond transport level security like TLS or SSL)

any way, simply encrypting the parameters \ messages should be simple enough